# access debian guest from out side world

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridging

I Installed debian on a vbox with bridged networking on windows 2008 server
my host configuration

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::70d6:9dff:68b5:a192%11
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.140.150.11
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.140.0.1
```

my guest confuguation in /etc/network/interfaces

```
address  10.140.150.12
netmask 255.255.0.0
network 10.140.150.0
```

I can ping my guest from the host and other machines on the same network and they can ping the guest too
the problem is that I can't access the guest from out side this network while I can Access the host well

my configuration are:

```
inet 10.40.0.129  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.40.0.255
```

Can any one find the Issue I have

Comment: Is there a firewall enabled in the host?